# Task lists that are editable by individual contributors Sharepoint 2013

Tags: task-list

On our team, we have daily tasks that we perform, and as of yet have no way of tracking completion. These are tasks that everyone will be completing individually. I know how to create a task and assign multiple people to it, but as I can see, I can't have it show who's completed it, only whether it's been completed or not. I want to be able to create a task list that everyone can individually mark completed, without having to create the same task 17 times for our team members. Preferably without Javascript because I would have to send that in to be approved, which can be done if necessary. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? We are on SharePoint 2013